# Evaluate the line integral over $\gamma$ of |z-1||dz| where $\gamma (t)=e^{it}$, $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

So far I can figure out that f(z)=|z-1| but I am having trouble parametrizing f(z) to get z(t) along with its derivative and am trying to understand what to do with the $\gamma (t)=e^{it}$.

can anyone offer some advice?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Since $dz=ie^{it}dt$ on $\gamma$ (counterclockwise), you may write
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{\Large \gamma}|z-1||dz|&=\int_{\large 0}^{\large 2\pi}|e^{it}-1||ie^{it}|\:dt\\\\
&=\int_{\large 0}^{\large 2\pi}|e^{it}-1|\:dt\\\\
&=\int_{\large 0}^{\large 2\pi}|2i|\left|e^{it/2}\right|\left|\frac{{e^{it/2}-e^{-it/2}}}{2i}\right|\:dt\\\\
&=\int_{\large 0}^{\large 2\pi}\left|\sin (t/2)\right|\:dt\\\\
&=4.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: can you explain how you get from step two to three and three to four?  thanks.

Comment: @cambelot Observe that $$e^{it}-1=e^{it/2}\left({e^{it/2}-e^{-it/2}}\right)= (2i)\:e^{it/2}\frac{{e^{it/2}-e^{-it/2}}}{2i}$$ Thanks.

Comment: how did you eliminate |ie^{it}| then proceed to just |e^{it}-1|

Comment: @cambelot You have $|e^{it}|=|\cos t+i\sin t|=\sqrt{\cos^2 t+\sin^2 t}=1$ and also $|i|=|e^{i\pi/2}|=1$.